# hadoop dfsadmin -report not giving all the datanodes

Tags: hadoop, installation, nodes, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a hdoop cluster of 6 nodes. 
I node is a master nodes. All the nodes, including master node, are running TaskTracker & DataNode. 
The command

```
   hadoop dfsadmin -report
```

Return only 3 data nodes including the DataNode running at master node. There are no errors on the console. Master node can SSH to these nodes and DataNode is running on the unreported nodes. I checked SSH loging to the un-reported nodes and by executing he JPS command. All the slave nodes have the following output:

ubuntu@slave2:¬/hadoop/logs$ jps

5007 TaskTracker

4868 DataNode

5261 Jps

How to look for unreported DataNodes in the dfsadmin command?

Comment: Did you check `slaves` file in the `namenode` ?

Comment: Did you check all the namenode & datanode logs on all the servers? They probably state some connectivity problems. `slaves` file is probably ok as the processes are started.